# A fetch request must be a simple member access expression; '[100002]' is a SubQueryExpression instead

Tags: linq, fluent-nhibernate

I get the following error:
"A fetch request must be a simple member access expression; '[100002]' is a SubQueryExpression instead. Parameter name: relatedObjectSelector"

Below is my query:

```
var query =
    session.Query<Customer().Where(cus => cus.CustomerId == customerId)
    .Fetch(c => c.CustomerType) // Parent CustomerType
    .Fetch(c => c.CustomerOrders) // Child Collection of orders
    .ThenFetch(co => co.Select(it => it.Item)).ToList(); // A parent of CustomerOrder
```

If I take the 'ThenFetch' out then I do not get that error. However, I do need to retrieve the Item object.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just apply the select on the resulting CustomerOrder?

```
var query =
    session.Query<Customer().Where(cus => cus.CustomerId == customerId)
    .Fetch(c => c.CustomerType)
    .Fetch(c => c.CustomerOrder)
    .Select(co => co.Item)
    .ToList();
```

Comment: .Select takes Customer and not CustomerOrder